# Последняя активность telethon

Tags: python, telethon

Можно ли как-то сменить настройку последней активности через telethon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спустя 2 года, но все таки ответ будет

У telethon по этому поводу есть статья на GitHub [вот ссылка](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/wiki/Privacy-settings), только в ней не все разъяснено.

Я писал так, по короче и удобнее

```
await client(SetPrivacyRequest(
    key=telethon.tl.types.InputPrivacyKeyStatusTimestamp(),
    rules=[telethon.tl.types.InputPrivacyValueDisallowAll()]))
```

Это настройка последней активности, время последней активности видит **Никто**. Если хотите поставить другое, кто видит, то пишите `telethon.tl.types.InputPrivacyValue` и после него выбирайте что вам нужно, всего есть 8 ключей, и 8 правил, в статье которую предоставил выше можете посмотреть(там название похожие в модуле, думаю поймете)

Чтобы поставить другой ключ, пишите `telethon.tl.types.InputPrivacyKey`, и потом выбираете что вам нужно.